# What Does MixPanel Offer that I can't get on Google Analytics?

Tags: analytics

I am testing MixPanel Right now and I want to see if it has anything that I can't get on Google Analytics?

Comment: Please refer answers to this question on Quora as well: http://www.quora.com/What-does-Mixpanel-do-that-Google-Analytics-is-incapable-of-doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short MixPanel has specialized itself on Event based tracking not Page view/based tracking. This differentiation is quite important, since you have to decide what the events are in your app. You then can use these events and then chain them together in a chain (ordered set of events) that let you build funnels, segment (group and build Ven Diagram like overlaps) etc.

Example: Let's say you build a highly interactive JS application that is less page oriented but instead event oriented. You want to track these events (user buys credits, user shares via FB, user creates message, user logs in, user logs out etc.). MixPanel would be the better choice.